# Не работает неранество в pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
var
x,y:integer;
begin
readln(x); 
readln(y);
if (x=90) or (y=90) or (180-(x+y)=90) then
  writeln('прямоугольный');
if (x>90) or (y>90) or (180-(x+y)>90) and (180-(x+y)<>90) and (x<>90) and (y<>90) then
  writeln('тупоугольный');
if (x<90) or (y<90) or (180-(x+y)<90) and (180-(x+y)<>90) and (x<>90) and (y<>90) then
  writeln('остроугольный');
  
end.
```

Цель программы-определить, что треугольник является прямоугольным, однако после того, как она определяет треугольник прямоугольным, программа продолжает выполняться и пишет, что треугольник прямоугольный и остроугольный. Я попытался решить эту проблему, добавив неравенство 90 градусам в условие остроугольности и тупоугольности, но оно все равно не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Оно" как раз работает! Именно так, как написано - все три проверки у тебя независимые, а поскольку в каждом прямоугольном треугольнике есть два острых угла, то сначала определяется, что треугольнык прямоугольный, а потом, что он остроугольный. Замени два последних `if` на `else if`.

---

Упрощения:

- `(180-(x+y)=90)` это то же самое, что `(x+y=90)`
- `(180-(x+y)<>90)` это то же самое, что `(x+y<>90)`
- `(180-(x+y)>90)` это то же самое, что `(x+y<90)`
- `(180-(x+y)<90)` это то же самое, что `(x+y>90)`

Не усложняй жизнь себе и другим :)